# onclick play/pause audio separate buttons html5

Tags: html, button, onclick, playback, pause

My coding looks wrong and renders no sound. I'm sure my syntax is completely wrong.

My application: I have two buttons for playing a single audio file on each. I want each button to play the audio onclick, but to pause or stop playing when either button is clicked and continue playing the onclick button. It's desirable to pause either button while the other is playing, but to stop either playing when clicking. Essentially, the goal here is for audio playback of a same sound of differing quality for listener comparison.

Any correction is greatly appreciated.

I started with this, which played, but onclick of either they overlapped and I couldn't make the other stop.

```
<audio id="sound1" src="audio1.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
  <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary display-4" onclick="document.getElementById('sound1').play();"><span class="mbri-play mbr-iconfont mbr-iconfont-btn"></span>DEMO 1</button>

<audio id="sound2" src="audio2.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
  <button class="btn btn-md btn-white display-4" onclick="document.getElementById('sound2').play();"><span class="mbri-play mbr-iconfont mbr-iconfont-btn"></span>DEMO 2</button>
```

No playback control, so I went this route.

```
<audio id="sound1" src="audio1.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
  <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary display-4" onclick="document.getElementById('sound1').aud_play_pause();"><span class="mbri-play mbr-iconfont mbr-iconfont-btn"></span>DEMO 1</button>

<audio id="sound1" src="audio2.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
  <button class="btn btn-md btn-white display-4" onclick="document.getElementById('sound1').aud_play_pause();"><span class="mbri-play mbr-iconfont mbr-iconfont-btn"></span>DEMO 2</button>  

  <script>
function aud_play_pause() {
  var sound1 = document.getElementById("sound1");
  if (sound1.paused) {
    sound2.play();
  } else {
    sound1.pause();
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Does someone out there have expertise in this area?

Comment: Hey guys. Anybody have a solution? Still need ideas. Thanks.